# Error with referencing a variable before assignment python

Tags: python, reference, variable-assignment

I have a for loop as part of a larger function:

```
for table in tables_list:
   if table["file"] == file:
      table_name = table["table_name"]
      break
log.info(f"table: {table_name}")
```

I am getting an error saying the variable is being referenced before assignment `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'table_name' referenced before assignment"`. Not sure why this is the case because isn't the variable table_name assigned when the condition is met in the loop and then the loop stops?

Comment: What happens if table["file"] never equals file, the variable table_name is never created...

Comment: This is a design issue. What do you want to happen when there are no tables in the list or no tables that meet your criteria? Code that implements your choices should be included. The exception raised may already be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the `table_name` before the loop there might be a chance for unsatisfied this condition `table["file"] == file` so `table_name` will be undeclared at that moment.

```
table_name = None # declare here
for table in tables_list:
   if table["file"] == file:
      table_name = table["table_name"]
      break
log.info(f"table: {table_name}")
```